# Slick slider not being responsive when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a image slider in WordPress using slick slider. I am using center mode I want one image centered with one on each side slightly showing. But I am having a few problems. Firstly when I resize the window slick slider doesn't calculate the new image widths until I interact with the slider, this is problem is not present in the demo. Secondly the images on each side aren't showing like they should.

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/xLQwEb

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  slidesToShow: 1,
});
```

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide img{
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/stairs_one2200.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/stairs_two2200.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/stairs_one2200.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/JyeGJO) look for the window resize event an add this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.my-slider')[0].slick.refresh();
});
```

Comment: This worked! I was having issues resizing on min-height, really odd. The other answers didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Answer from slick creator, Ken Wheeler, himself:

`$('.slider-class').slick('setPosition');`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107099/3396866

Answer (score 2):

Run the `slick` method on window resize to recalculate the image dimensions.

```
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
  $('.carousel').slick('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all I needed was some css styles and to add the latest jQuery to wordpress. Check my codepen to see the css if you're have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use to resize my slack carousel, whenever the browser window changes height.

```
    var MARGIN_TOP_BOTTOM = 15;

    $(window).on('init resize', function () {
        var newWindowHeight = $(this).height();
        newWindowHeight -= (MARGIN_TOP_BOTTOM * 2);

        $(".cssCarousel").css("margin", MARGIN_TOP_BOTTOM + "px 0px");
        $(".slick-slide").css("height", newWindowHeight + "px");
        $(".slick-slide img").css("height", newWindowHeight + "px");
    });
```

As you can see, I leave a small (15px) gap at the top & bottom.