# Slick slider Responsive breakpoints not working at 576px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, sass

I have implemented a slick slider which works fine in 1200px, but as soon I resize, it breaks down. I need to implement 3 slides in 1200px, 2 slides in 786px and 1 slide in 576px screen with equal space between each slide. When I tried to put a margin between each slide, the first slide, cuts off. Here is my code.

- **JQUERY**

```
jQuery('.multiple-items').slick({
        prevArrow: '<button class="image-prev w-30 w-md-40 w-lg-50 h-25 h-lg-50 h-md-40 border-0 bg-bfp-primary position-absolute rotate180"></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button class="image-next w-30 w-md-40 w-lg-50 h-25 h-lg-50 h-md-40 border-0 bg-bfp-primary position-absolute "></button>',
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1200,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                infinite: true,
                dots: false,
                mobileFirst: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                mobileFirst: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 576,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                mobileFirst: true,
            }
        }

    ]

});
jQuery('.slick-list').find('.slick-active').addClass('slick-slide-margin');
```

- **PHP**

```
<div class="ml-7 ml-xl-24 mr-0">
    <div class="pt-6.8 pb-9">
        <h2 class="font-inter-medium fz-20 text-theme-blue-dark leading-24">Photo Gallery</h2>
            <div class="multiple-items pt-4" >
                <?php 
                while ($photo_gallery_query->have_posts()) : $photo_gallery_query->the_post();
                        $featured_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');?>
                    <div>
                        <img src="<?php echo $featured_image_url; ?>">
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; 
                wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- **SASS**

```
.slick-slide-margin {
    @extend .w-270;
    @extend .mr-xl-7;
    @extend .mr-3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Kuldeep Upreti and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Just to make sure, have you tried to compare your solution to their demos?

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Also this thread might be helpful,

[Slick slider not being responsive when resizing the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939631/slick-slider-not-being-responsive-when-resizing-the-window)

Often, the kind of problem you describe, is pretty easy to solve once you figure it out. Most of the times it's just a minor fix, like a missing configuration, event and so on.

To make it easier to help, you can also set up a demo using a service like CodePen (or any other similar service),

https://codepen.io/

Let us know if you're not being able to solve your problem with these links. :-)

Comment: Those links really helped me to solve my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help. :)
A friendly advice is to mark a response as accepted as it makes it easier to see which question that is still "open". That helps other users of StackOverflow.

Anyway, great that you solved your problem. :-)

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue when the screen size is less than 710px. Is there any fix?

Comment: Here's the link to my fork: https://codepen.io/IOIIOOIO/pen/jOMNbZZ